# MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) compiler

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction

I packaged the 7.13 MCR compiler with my files (via desploytool).

I have some questions with assuming the client installed the MCR.

**1) If the client doesn't have MATLAB, but just the MCR. he will be able to run my application by the MCR?**

**2) how can the client make the MCR compiler to be the default?**

I tried:

```
mbuild -setup

Please choose your compiler for building standalone MATLAB applications:

Would you like mbuild to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler:
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2010a\sys\lcc
[2] Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0

[0] None

Compiler:
```

but I didn't see the MCR. his location is something like: *C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v713* but I don't know what is the exactly path. **should I know it?**

**3) should I have to make a bat file which configures the MCR to be the default compiler?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MCR is not a compiler.

MCR is an abbreviation for MATLAB Compiler Runtime. When you use `deploytool`  or `mcc` (available with MATLAB Compiler or the MATLAB Builder products), it converts your MATLAB program into a standalone component (e.g. an executable or library). You then give your end user the component and the MCR, and the component runs against the MCR instead of MATLAB.

The answer to your question i) is yes, your users only need the MCR, not MATLAB. Your users should not need to interact with `mbuild` at all, (and if they don't have MATLAB anyway, they can't). `mbuild` is used by you when preparing to create the component, not by your users when running it.

Comment: ok, thank you!
so the component (exe file) will run automatically against the MCR, right?

Comment: Should do, yes. Your user just needs to install the MCR, and then your .exe should run against it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you confuse things. MCR is [*MATLAB Compiler Runtime*](http://www.mathworks.se/products/compiler/mcr/index.html). It does not provide any compiler, it allows one to run MATLAB programs compiled and deployed with [mcc](http://www.mathworks.se/help/compiler/mcc.html).

So the answer to your first question: yes, your client needs only to install MCR to run the programs you compile for him using mcc.

The answer to the other questions: there is no compiler..